# Spring Web Client Proxy for REST annotated interfaces

Tags: java, spring, rest

Is there a module in Spring for proxy generation using REST annotated interfaces at client side?

Like JAX-RS (RestEasy) does, for example.

We have module-api.jar with

`@RequestMapping("/module")
public interface IModuleService {`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resource/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Resource getResource(String id);
```

`}`

Include dependency module-api.jar to both server & client.

At server side we use @RestController for class implementing our IModuleService interface.

At client side would like to use something like this:

```
IModuleService service = RestClient.createProxy(IModuleService.class);
Resource resource = service.getResource("my-resource");
```

All staff for REST calls must be incapsulated inside this proxy.

Comment: IModuleService service = RestClient.createProxy(url, IModuleService.class);